# Ubuntu apps development using "quickly"

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
I need to install "quickly" package,to be able to develop new application. How I can do that?
Also I am not finding the "quickly" app in Ubuntu Software Center? How can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

The "Quickly" project was abandoned after Ubuntu 14.04.

It's dead. Use a different tool.

Comment: Also if I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and used quickly it will not work??

Comment: Community Support for Ubuntu 14.04 ended in April 2019. We no longer answer questions about it.

Comment: what other tools I can use to develop an application?

Comment: There are dozens. Perhaps hundreds. Please open a new question clearly explaining exactly what you want to do. Generally, it involves learning a programming language. Generic advice: Learn Python3.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly apparently enabled software development on Ubuntu with python and GTK.

Software development is too broad a topic to address in a single post.

Ask yourself what kind of application you want to create. Discuss your ideas with others.

Regards,
mondotofu